# Error in email configuration for Redmine Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sendmail, redmine

My configuration file contains the following code:

```
production:
    email_delivery:
       delivery_method: :sendmail
development:
    email_delivery:
       delivery_method: :sendmail
```

But I'm still getting the following error while running Redmine application in production mode.

```
  NoMethodError (undefined method `error' for 0:Fixnum):
  app/models/mailer.rb:431:in `deliver_mail'
  app/models/mailer.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in deliver_issue_edit'
  app/models/issue.rb:826:in `each_notification'
  app/models/mailer.rb:85:in `block in deliver_issue_edit'
  app/models/journal.rb:77:in `block in each_notification'
  app/models/journal.rb:75:in `each'
  app/models/journal.rb:75:in `each_notification'
  app/models/mailer.rb:84:in `deliver_issue_edit'
  app/models/journal.rb:190:in `send_notification'
  app/models/journal.rb:54:in `save'
  app/models/issue.rb:1515:in `create_journal'
  app/models/issue.rb:165:in `create_or_update'
  app/controllers/issues_controller.rb:478:in `block in save_issue_with_child_records'
  app/controllers/issues_controller.rb:466:in `save_issue_with_child_records'
  app/controllers/issues_controller.rb:188:in `update'
```

I have no clue about why I am getting this error and I have also checked the configuration against Redmine documentation and action mailer configuration. I still can't figure out the cause.
Has anybody faced a similar issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you just post the header of your email configuration section in the configuration file or are these your only settings? An email configuration section should look something like this:

```
production:  
 email_delivery:  
  delivery_method: :smtp
   smtp_settings:
   address: smtp.example.net
   port: 25
   domain: example.net
   authentication: :login
   user_name: redmine@example.net
   password: redmine
```

Refer to the Redmine [documentation](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/EmailConfiguration).

Comment: Actually the configuration worked as expected but I was getting issue while creating Issue in Redmine.After commenting out raise excpetion line It worked smoothly.